# Excel Charts - Bug when setting marker 3D parameters?

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel 2010 I'm trying to add 3D effect to my scatter plot using VBA. For some reason, as soon as I set the depth to a certain value, Excel automatically sets the width to 6 pt, and vice-versa if I'm trying to set the width.

Here's my code snippet, which reproduces the behavior. Here since I'm setting the width last (`BevelTopInset`), the depth is gets overwritten to 6 pt:

```
Set oCht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(1, 1, 400, 400).Chart

oCht.ChartType = xlXYScatter
oCht.ApplyLayout (1)
oCht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
Set oSer = oCht.SeriesCollection(1)
oSer.Values = 1
oSer.XValues = 1
oSer.MarkerSize = 40
oSer.MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleSquare
oSer.MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
oSer.MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
oSer.Border.ColorIndex = xlNone

With oSer.Format.ThreeD
    .Visible = True
    .BevelTopDepth = 20 ' will be overwritten to 6 after the next instruction
    .BevelTopInset = 20
End With
```

Is it possible to set both width and depth programmatically?

Comment: You need to post the full code for the graph creation.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Thank you for your comment. I now posted the full code for the graph creation.